# Laravel won't let me save pagination variable in an array

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I need to return a json with all products and stores.

I tried this

```
    $products = $products->paginate(20);
    $stores=$this->getStores();
    return ['product'=> $products, 'stores' =>$stores];
```

but $products returns empty. (If i run "return $products" it works fine)

Is there something i can do? Why laravel doesn't let me have the pagination in an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
return ['product'=> $products->toArray(), 'stores' =>$stores];
```

or

```
return Response::json(
  array(
    'products' => $products->toArray(),
    'stores' => $stores,
  ), 200
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this :

```
return Response::json(
  array(
    'products' => $products,
    'stores' => $stores,
  ), 200
);
```

You also need to 'use' the Response facade:
`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;`

Comment: I tried that but i had the same result. For some reason if i paginate the results i cannot return them in the array.. if i change `$products = $products->paginate(20);` to `$products = $products->get();` it works fine, but i want to paginate it..

Comment: @George,Check this out : http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination#converting-results-to-json